# MySQL syntax error when using sqlite3 query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I just wanted to switch from sqlite3 to using MySQL but I get errors in this query:

```
SELECT 
   metapp_notif.id, 
   name, 
   age, 
   place, 
   note, 
   metapp_notif.lat, 
   metapp_notif.longt, 
   haslatlong, 
   dati, 
   ntype, 
   grpm_id, 
   image, 
   send_id, 
   pro.latitude, 
   pro.longtitude, 
   metapp_notif.dati, 
   metapp_notif.activity 
FROM   (metapp_notif 
        join (metapp_profil 
              join metapp_userlocation 
                ON metapp_profil.user_id = metapp_userlocation.user_id) AS pro 
          ON metapp_notif.send_id = pro.user_id) 
WHERE  metapp_notif.rec_id =% d;
```

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'pro on metapp_notif.send_id=pro.user_id) where
>   metapp_notif.rec_id=2' at line 1

I was searching for differences between sqlite3 and mysql but can't figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `where metapp_notif.rec_id=%d;` Try that with `where metapp_notif.rec_id like '%d';`. Add the quote and `like`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax in `Mysql`

```
SELECT metapp_notif.id, 
       name, 
       age, 
       place, 
       note, 
       metapp_notif.lat, 
       metapp_notif.longt, 
       haslatlong, 
       dati, 
       ntype, 
       grpm_id, 
       image, 
       send_id, 
       latitude, 
       longtitude, 
       metapp_notif.dati, 
       metapp_notif.activity 
FROM   metapp_profil 
       join metapp_notif 
         ON metapp_notif.send_id = metapp_profil.user_id 
       join metapp_userlocation 
         ON metapp_profil.user_id = metapp_userlocation.user_id 
WHERE  metapp_notif.rec_id like '% d';  -- Not sure what you are trying to do here
```

Comment: im not sure how this joins work now. in what order it is computed... but works with no errors. sorry for not specifying that %d thing. it is just string formatter and is later substituted for a number comming as a parameter.